# onBoarding goes to next activity automatically after few seconds

Tags: android-studio

I'm implementing onBoarding screen that appear the first time the user opens the app. However, I'm facing an issue, it opens the onBoarding screen and after few seconds it goes to next Activity(MainActivity) by itself!!

How can I stop that from happening?

Here is my SplashScreen Activity:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(4000);
                    onBoardingScreen = getSharedPreferences("onBoardingScreen", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    boolean isFirstTime = onBoardingScreen.getBoolean("firstTime", true);
                    if(isFirstTime)
                    {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = onBoardingScreen.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("firstTime",false);
                    editor.commit();
                    //startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,onBoarding.class ));
                   //  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), onBoarding.class);
                     Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, onBoarding.class);
                     startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){

                }

            }
        }; thread.start();
```

and onBoarding Activity:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_on_boarding);
        //Hooks
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.slider);
        dotsLayout = findViewById(R.id.dots);
        letsGetStarted = findViewById(R.id.get_started_btn);
        next_btn = findViewById(R.id.next_btn);
        if (getActionBar() != null) {
            getActionBar().hide();
        }
        letsGetStarted.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(onBoarding.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        //Call adapter
        sliderAdapter = new sliderAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sliderAdapter);
        //Dots
        addDots(0);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(changeListener);
    }
```

and the Manifest:

```
  <activity
            android:name=".onBoarding"
            android:exported="false"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Invited1">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Why does the onboarding Activity opens the MainActivity after seconds? How can I fix this? it should go to next activity on button click not by itself!